# User Input Issue in Java

Tags: java, user-input

I'm trying to make a program that is similar to a Type To Learn program and eventually develop it into an app. I'm aware that it's really easy to just have a button that checks whether the user input is equal to the prompted word by doing something like if(userInput.equals(promptedWord)), but I want to have it similar to Quizlet in that the moment the user has the right answer typed up, the program marks it correct and moves on to the next word if you get what i mean. Basically, there should be no enter button. Instead, the moment the user types in the right word, the program realizes it and marks it right and moves on. I'm really puzzled on how to approach it this way though. I've been trying to research ways in which I can access the user's input the moment he's typing it in but I can't really find anything about it. Is there anyway I can do this, or is it extremely difficult to do?

Thanks, and let me know if I should try to add more information!

Comment: Are familiar with [`EventListeners`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/eventsandcomponents.html)?  I assumed you use [`Swing`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/start/index.html)

Comment: OH right. I should probably use a key listener right?

Comment: That depends. You might, for example, decide to use [`CaretListeners`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/caretlistener.html).

Comment: Do you think that TextWatchers could also work?

Answer (score 0):

On a very abstract level -- just as you can check the user input upon detecting the button's click, so you can check the user input upon detecting the user's key-typing. The task would be to set up the event listeners to detect the key-typing events (e.g., by listening on the text field).

Comment: Oh right I completely forgot about listeners! Let me give it a shot and hopefully it works out.

Answer (score 0):

There are a Listener called `KeyListener` 
so you can make your TextField or TextArea whatsoever listen `KeyType` via `KeyListener`
So make it know the action is based on every time the keyboard is typed, you can use `getText().equal("your answer")` to check if the answer is correct or not.

Hope it would help

Comment: Isn't TextWatchers is an Android class
I never develop Android before, I couldn't say.